# How to use TAdoQuery to ALTER IB stored procedure

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, ado, alter, interbase

We test migration of a D5 project (using IB 2009 Server and IBProvider) to XE6, keeping the same IB server an ADO provider. The project heavily uses stored procedures (SPs).

At database creation (programmatically, with IB API), after having created (with TAdoQuery) the tables, exceptions and declaring (also with TAdoQuery) several UDFs, we do the SPs creation (still with TAdoQuery) in two passes.

pass 1. Using SQL command CREATE PROCEDURE, we create **all** SPs with trivial body, e.g.

```
PROCEDURE "SP_WITH_PARAMETERS"("IN_PARAM" VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS ("OUT_PARAM" VARCHAR(5))
AS
BEGIN
  EXIT;   <-- trivial body
END;
```

pass 2. Using ALTER PROCEDURE, each SP is endowed with its proper body, e.g.

```
PROCEDURE "SP_WITH_PARAMETERS"("IN_PARAM" VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS ("OUT_PARAM" VARCHAR(5))
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(C_CODE)
  FROM CODES
  WHERE C_CODE < :IN_PARAM
  INTO :OUT_PARAM;
END;
```

*For anybody who would like to do a test:* The metadata of table CODES referred to in this particular body, is

```
CREATE TABLE "CODES"
("C_CODE" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("C_CODE"));
```

The two passes are to overcome the obstacle of SPs inter dependencies.

In D5 it was necessary to respect an ugly "convention" consisting in using in TAdoQuery.SQL, double-colon (instead of colon) to prefix SP parameters referred to within SQL commands occurring within SP body. Imagine the above SP - the whole body of which is a single SQL command - with its colons doubled. That was in D5 where SPs creation worked "as expected", no matter the details of the "ugly" convention.

Now we are in XE6 and we rapidly noticed that in that particular case - let us call it "SP with parameters" (SPWP) - our D5 approach fails because IB doesn't tolerate double-colon which was (probably) preprocessed in D5. Unfortunately, with simple colons in TAdoQuery.Sql we don't reach the goal. We get

```
EOleException 
ErrorCode=-2146824580 ($800A0E7C) 
Msg=<"Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided"
```

which suggests that now it's ADO's turn to be unsatisfied.

**Question:**
How, using TAdoQuery and SQL command ALTER PROCEDURE, one can alter the first of the above SPs into the second one?

Comment: My very first guess is that the query prepared a parameter for that `:OUT_PARAM`. So my first attempt would be turning the query object's `ParamCheck` to False.

Comment: Don't you need to switch the terminators to prevent early execution of the statement? Something like `SET TERM ^ ;` before and `SET TERM ; ^` after?

Comment: @TLama. I use ParamCheck:=false

Comment: @Roald. I use TAdoQuery in Delphi project, not IBConsole.

Comment: Did you set param check off before or after entering the sql statement? Because there might still be params automatically created. Do you clear the params list beforehand?

Comment: @Roald. Well seen! ParamCheck was disabled *after* SQL assignment. Thank you. I have still issues but they seem to be of another nature.
How I can express my appreciation of your answer?

Comment: I guess I'll make this into an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning SQL to an TAdoQuery in code, make sure you have set `ParamCheck := False` *before* assigning the SQL statements. Otherwise, the `Params` list will still be populated.

Comment: That's what [`OP confirmed me`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156396/how-to-use-tadoquery-to-alter-ib-stored-procedure#comment44685052_28156396).